# How to use multiple bash commands in single lines

Tags: linux, unix

OS: Linux RedHat

Bash: 3.5

I have 2 commands below to get list of files with status of them and another command for footprint.
I want to find the way to combine them together in single line.

Here's my mentioned commands.

1. `find "$PWD" -type f ! -iname '*thumbs.db*' -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%y %s %n"`
2. `find "$PWD" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum -b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work? Do a `man` on `xargs`.

```
find $PWD -type f ! -iname '*thumbs.db*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c 'stat --printf "%y %s %n " {} ; sha1sum -b {}'
```

If you do not want the file name repeated twice:

```
find $PWD -type f ! -iname '*thumbs.db*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c 'stat --printf "%y %s %n " {} ; sha1sum -b {} | cut -d\  -f1'
```

There needs to be 2 blank spaces after `d\` in `cut` command.

Comment: it's works, but didn't put the result together as list sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with -exec in find command itself.

```
find $PWD -type f ! -iname '*thumbs.db*' -exec stat -c "%y %s %n" {} \; -exec sha1sum -b {} \;
```